# how to set a table background image

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-color

I am having table and p tag inside div tag with background image. i want to make the background of table and p both transparent so that image appears without boxes. I tried

```
style="background-color:transparent;"
```

with p table td tr td tags. but still boxes are appearing.
How could I make the whole table and p tag transparent.

here is the image below:
[image: That Blue strip below buttons is background image]
That Blue strip below buttons is background image
and following is the css code

```
div#registration_form
{
    width: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px,auto;
    margin: auto;
}
tr,td,th
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
p
{
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Use the web inspector and find out which element has the background and figure out which element you need to change the background color.

Comment: Create a code snippet on http://jsbin.com or similar place, so it's easier to give you a correct answer.

Comment: @www139: I just have that div tag(with background image) inside my html file with a 4x2 table and a 1 line para.

Comment: Ok ;) By 'boxes' do you mean the border?

Comment: @www139:  I have added a image. whats happening.

Comment: @jo-asakura: i tried the same code at jsbin.com. it is working fine. but on my system its working as shown in image.

Comment: @Himanshu Singh Could you create a jsfiddle to provide something tangible for tinkering? It will make it easier for everyone to answer your question.

Comment: here is the  jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qhvmka73/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the background color to show through, you need to set `background: transparent` on a few more items that currently have white backgrounds (`form` and `tbody`). Here is the final code to set transparency:

```
tr,td,th
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:0px;
}
p, form, tbody
{
    background: transparent;
}
```

And here is the full code and **live demo** of the result with red background showing through:

```css
div#registration_form {
  width: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px, auto;
  margin: auto;
}
tr,
td,
th {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
}
p,
form,
tbody {
  background: transparent;
}
* {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #888888;
}
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #008dde;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="registration_form" style="background:red;">
  <form action="RegistrationServlet" method="post">
    <table style="background:transparent;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          First Name
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="first_name" name="firstname">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Last Name
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="last_name" name="lastname">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Password
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Confirm Password
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirmpassword">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
    </p>

  </form>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/qhvmka73/2/

Comment: thanks. just after experimenting on your fiddle i got my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will resolve your issue:**

Try this:

```
table*, p{
   background:none transparent;
   border:0px;
}
```

Comment: background of already is set to transparent and border didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but is this what you want to accomplish https://jsfiddle.net/r22nd8gg/? If it is just add this to your css

```
tbody {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

td {
  color: transparent;
}

form {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the margin of the `p` tag, that is a default styling of the paragraphs in html.

https://jsfiddle.net/qhvmka73/1/

Just add this

```
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Red line disappears.

P.D.: I love firefox's inspector :)